# How to normalize my db schema for a quiz application?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I am putting together a quiz application.   (I'm calling each quiz a "challenge")

I have a "challenge" table and a "challenge_question" table which is pretty straightforward.

```
challenge table:
id
name
num_questions (I want to randomize and only display a certain number of Qs per each challenge)

challenge_question table:
id
challenge_id
question (text of the question)
required (some questions will be required to be displayed per each challenge)
question_type (here I indicate what type of question: Mult. choice, T/F, Ordering, or Fill-in-the-blank)
```

Where I'm having trouble in normalization is with the types of question options:  Multiple choice, true/false, ordering, and fill-in-the-blank. I wonder, should I have a separate table for each type of challenge-question-option? Or is it possible to combine these into one somehow..

If I combined all possible options into a single table, it might look be something like this

```
challenge_options table:
id
challenge_question_id
option (text field, can be used for both multiple choice and for fill-in-the-blank style questions)
is_true (boolean field for true/false questions)
is_correct (boolean, used to determine multiple choice answer)
ordering_option_1 
ordering_option_2
ordering_option_3
ordering_option_4 (these ordering fields would store the correct sequence of an ordering style of question)
```

This really strikes me as less than ideal.  Actually, I don't see how the ordering_options would work out correctly at all.  Wouldn't I need to have each of those be a separate option?  Surely there must be a better way.  Any suggestions/criticisms or alternate approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of option I would use another table option_type with a PK and a name field and use a fk-relationship in challenge_options. You can easily add new kinds of challenges.

I am not sure if I would use is_true / is_correct within challenge_options. I would use a second table with user_id, challenge_options_id and a boolean correct/false.